# service fabric reliable collection for product catalog (e-commerce)?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

does reliable collection is a good option (query performance, flexible model, etc) for millions of products or i have to see toward nosql database ?

Thanks

Comment: There are many pros/cons for various types of data storage applications. However, SFRC and NoSQL are extremely different to oneanother. I would recommend reading up on both extensively before running "millions of products" off either.

Answer (score 1):

Reliable Collection are basically collection types that are reliably persisted across replicas, they are not databases, nor do they offer database characteristics. They share some features with database, mainly transactionality. The data (documents) you store are fairly flexible but thats about it.

If you are looking for something with database characteristics such as queryability and indexing then I suggest a database solution instead.

As for performance, it depends. If you are retrieving a document by it's key then SFRC are fast, in all other scenarios you likely need to build someting that explicitly supports that request.

There is nothing that prevents you from working with database (relational or NoSQL) in Service Fabric alongsides working with Reliable Collections.